# Service not recognized by Symfony

Tags: symfony, lexikjwtauthbundle

I have a concern with the following service in my project:

```
app.security.guardAuthenticatorLoginPassword:
      class: AppBundle\Security\LoginPasswordAuthenticator
      arguments: ["@router"]
app.jwt_token_authenticator:
      class: AppBundle\Security\JwtAuthenticator
      arguments: ['@doctrine.orm.entity_manager', '@lexik_jwt_authentication.encoder']
```

I feel that whatever I do it is not recognized by my program ..

I have been looking for a few hours already but I do not understand why it does not work. While I have both my LoginPasswordAuthenticator and JwtAuthenticator classes in the specified path ..

Thank you in advance for your help

Comment: What "service not recognized" means exactly? Do you have an error message?

Comment: Maybe you should clear cache?

Answer (score 0):

Here is some potentials issues:
_ Clear the cache
_ Check if you didn't forget a 'use' for your differents classes
_ Give to your services a name (and why not an alias) and use it when you call your service:

```
app.security.guardAuthenticatorLoginPassword:
  class: AppBundle\Security\LoginPasswordAuthenticator
  arguments: ["@router"]
  tags:
      - { name: login.password.authenticator, alias: login.auth }

app.jwt_token_authenticator:
  class: AppBundle\Security\JwtAuthenticator
  arguments:['@doctrine.orm.entity_manager','@lexik_jwt_authentication.encoder']
  tags:
      - { name: security.authenticator, alias: security.auth }
```

Comment: Are you suggesting that tags have something to do with aliases?  Two completely different concepts.

Comment: I'm just giving some potentials issues. I also had a problem with an unrecognized service when I used the name (here "app.jwt_token_authenticator") but when I set an alias and used it, it worked. So it costs nothing to try it.

Comment: If you say so.  Yes you can add custom attributes to tags and I suppose you could have one called alias.  But unless you update your compiler pass to use the custom tag then it's a waste of effort.  Especially with tags with different names.  Not to be cruel but it looks like your answer was just a copy/paste of the question.  No value added.